# How can I position text at a certain height according to another text aside

Tags: javascript, html, css, height

I'm very new with JS, and I don't even know whether what I try to do is doable. Some guys told me "try javascript", and google can't help me because it's too specific.

Ok so, firstly I have some huge text in the center of my page. So far so good. Call it the "main text"

Then, on the side of the main text, there has to be another column containing more text blocs. But this time, these blocs have to align with the height of specific words found in the main text.

You will probably understand better with this picture :
[image]

Any idea how to do that ? thanks !

Comment: I guess you can do that with pure css only.

Comment: you can do that just using html and css, why `javascript`?

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS and HTML, there is no need for JavaScript. In CSS you can use top:; to vertically align an element, e.g.

```
.text {
    top: 40%;
}
```

This will align an element with class "text" 40% of the pages height from the top. Use % as your units to make the text align correctly no matter what size the window is.

Comment: Well the trouble is that I will have other elements coming below in that column. And the text will be modified with the time.

Another illustration of what I'm trying to do is the "Comments" feature in Microsoft Office Word
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ubdflzn9n3a1ofv/blah4.png

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `JavaScript` to do what you're trying to do. All you need is `CSS` and `html`.
First of all you need to take a look at basic html layout [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_layout.asp).

Take a look at this [Fiddle](http://cssdeck.com/labs/ufgibyw8) its something similar to what you need

Comment: Well the trouble is that I will have other elements coming below in that column. And the main text will be modified with the time.

Another illustration of what I'm trying to do is the "Comments" feature in Microsoft Office Word
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ubdflzn9n3a1ofv/blah4.png

Answer (score 0):

Guys didn't understand you. It is really hard to find out the x/y position of the word in the div for a lot of reasons. The best way for you is to wrap the needed word with some tag (kind of span or something). Here's a [jQuery plugin](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html) to do that.
Then seems you will not have troubles to find out the position of your tag for example with [jquery position method](https://api.jquery.com/position/) and to give this position to your left column text.